# UML: Control Flow and Object Flow

Tags: uml

What's the difference between Control Flow and Object Flow in UML? When do I use one and when do I use the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In UML Activity Diagrams

*Control Flow* shows the flow of control from one action to the next

and

*Object flow* is a path along which objects or data can pass.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110822090051/http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html) is a detailed article on UML Activity Diagrams.